# Installing xdebug php profiler on unix

Tags: php, unix, profiling, xdebug

I want to start profiling some PHP code and I have that using `xdebug` and `webgrind` seems to be the way to go.

I downloaded xdebug and got these instructions..

```
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.2.3.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-2.2.3
```

Now, this may be a stupid question, but where exactly should I upload xdebug to so it can be unpacked? Does it matter? I assume it shouldn't be web-accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is assumed you have Apache2 + PHP5 working already.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php-pear
```

Now install xdebug thru PECL.

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Now we need to find where xdebug.so went (the compiled module)

```
martin@martin-dev:/$ find / -name 'xdebug.so' 2> /dev/null
/usr/lib/php5/20060613/xdebug.so
```

Then edit php.ini:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php/apache2/php.ini
```

Add the following line:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20060613/xdebug.so"
```

Then restart apache for changes to take effect

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and see

- http://xdebug.org/docs/install
- http://www.anil2u.info/2013/03/install-xdebug-in-ubuntu/
- http://2bits.com/articles/setting-up-xdebug-dbgp-for-php-on-debian-ubuntu.html
- http://www.michaelbender.net/?p=64